# mongoose-unique-validator ReferenceError: User is not defined

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm new to Node.js so I can't understand what I need to add, to make the default example from `mongoose-unique-validator` work. Here it is:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  uniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator'),
  userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    room: { type: String, required: true },
  });

userSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator);

const user = new User({ username: 'JohnSmith', room: 'asd');
user.save(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

The part with the user is not working, because of `ReferenceError: User is not defined`.
As far as I understand, the `user` part is the part that the library user should define, but I don't know what should be in there to make it work.

**TL; DR**:

I just want to make an [example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-unique-validator) work.
Thanks.

**Update**:

Ok, so I've added this line of code:

```js
const User = mongoose.model('Model', userSchema);
```

and it does not trows an error anymore. But it does not notify that `username` is not unique. It does not work yet. I want to check a valid username for the room. And that's all.

Answer (score 1):

you didn't define your model collection ("USER") try this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  uniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator'),
userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    room: { type: String, required: true },
  });

userSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator);


module.exports.User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

then :

```
const user = new User({ username: 'JohnSmith', room: 'asd');
user.save(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
})
```

Comment: try to console.log(User) .

Comment: console.log(User);
                ^

ReferenceError: User is not defined